# Add and remove dynamic component Angular

Tags: angular, indexing, dynamic, components

I have this code in Angular 12 and it works perfectly. The problem comes when changing the version from 12 to 16.

```
import {
  ComponentRef,
  ComponentFactoryResolver,
  ViewContainerRef,
  ViewChild,
  Component,
ViewRef
} from "@angular/core";
import { ChildComponent } from "../child/child.component";

@Component({
  selector: "app-parent",
  templateUrl: "./parent.component.html",
  styleUrls: ["./parent.component.css"]
})
export class ParentComponent {
  @ViewChild("viewContainerRef", { read: ViewContainerRef })
  VCR: ViewContainerRef;

  child_unique_key: number = 0;
  componentsReferences = Array<ComponentRef<ChildComponent>>()

  constructor(private CFR: ComponentFactoryResolver) {}

  createComponent() {
    let componentFactory = this.CFR.resolveComponentFactory(ChildComponent);

    let childComponentRef = this.VCR.createComponent(componentFactory);

    let childComponent = childComponentRef.instance;
    childComponent.unique_key = ++this.child_unique_key;
    childComponent.parentRef = this;

    // add reference for newly created component
    this.componentsReferences.push(childComponentRef);
  }

  remove(key: number) {
    if (this.VCR.length < 1) return;

    let componentRef = this.componentsReferences.filter(
      x => x.instance.unique_key == key
    )[0];

    let vcrIndex: number = this.VCR.indexOf(componentRef as any);

    // removing component from container
    this.VCR.remove(vcrIndex);

    // removing component from the list
    this.componentsReferences = this.componentsReferences.filter(
      x => x.instance.unique_key !== key
    );
  }
}
```

Example: https://stackblitz.com/edit/add-or-remove-dynamic-component?file=src%2Fapp%2Fparent%2Fparent.component.ts

The problem in Angular 16 is that vcrIndex is always -1 when not found.

```
let vcrIndex: number = this.VCR.indexOf(componentRef as any);

// removing component from container
this.VCR.remove(vcrIndex);
```

Any suggestions or how can I fix this without having to modify the way dynamic components are created?
I have tried several things such as adding an index or an identifier but I still have not been able to solve the problem.

Thx

I have looked to see if the VCR structure is different and I could add an identifier and search for it manually but I couldn't.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Not sure why exactly it worked before, guess it was just a coincidence. `this.VCR.indexOf` actually expects `ViewRef` and you pass a `ComponentRef` there casting it to `any`.

The fix is quite simple, you just need to pass `componentRef.hostView` to the `VCR.indexOf`:

```
let vcrIndex: number = this.VCR.indexOf(componentRef.hostView);
```

[Here is a working demo](https://stackblitz.com/edit/stackblitz-starters-vcnrvd) using Angular 17.

---

Just in case, `ComponentFactoryResolver` was deprecated long time ago (v13), and you can pass component type directly to the `this.VCR.createComponent`:

```
let childComponentRef = this.VCR.createComponent(ChildComponent);
```